# Why didn't Palpatine hire Bounty Hunters to kill the Queen of Naboo?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, the-phantom-menace

- Killing a Queen was an infiltration level task. Given enormous money at hand, the best of best Bounty Hunters could be hired to finish this task. Darth Maul couldn't stand a chance against military even if there were no Jedi involved. So, there was a chance of big failure if he failed to do it with surprise.
- It was known that Jedi were protecting the Queen, so a Force guy could barely dominate the situation.
- It was also going to reveal that Sith weren't extinct. And, this could sabotage their grand plan.

Why weren't Bounty Hunters hired to do this task?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because Sidious didn't want her dead at the time. He needed her to sign the treaty.

From [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html) for Episode 1:

First in an early scene, Captain Panaka realizes that Queen is in danger of being kidnapped.

> CAPT. PANAKA : **They need her to sign a treaty to make this invasion of
>   theirs legal. They can't afford to kill her.**

After the kidnapping fails, Sidious discusses the fact that he needs her alive.

> DARTH SIDIOUS : Destroy all high-ranking officials, Viceroy ...slowly...quietly. And Queen Amidala, has she signed the treaty?
>
> NUTE : She has disappeared, My Lord. One Naboo cruiser got past the blockade.
>
> DARTH SIDIOUS : **Viceroy, find her! I want that treaty signed.**
>
> NUTE : My Lord, it's impossible to locate the ship. It's out of our range.
>
> DARTH SIDIOUS : ...not for a Sith...
>
> A second SITH LORD appears behind DARTH SIDIOUS.
>
> DARTH SIDIOUS : (Cont'd) ...Viceroy, this is my apprentice. Lord Maul. He will find your lost ship.

Once Amidala has outrun her usefulness (episode 2), a bounty hunter is sent to kill her.

As to specifically why Sidious chose to send Maul instead of a bounty hunter to kidnap her, this is never spelled out in the movie, but Sidious and Maul's conversation implies that revealing the existence of the Sith is part of Sidious' plan.

> DARTH SIDIOUS : Move against the Jedi first...you will then have no
>   difficulty taking the Queen back to Naboo, where she will sign the treaty.
>
> DARTH MAUL : **At last we will reveal ourselves to the Jedi. At last we will
>   have revenge.**
>
> DARTH SIDIOUS : You have been well trained, my young apprentice, they will
>   be no match for you. It is too late for them to stop us now. **Everything is
>   going as planned.** The Republic will soon be in my command.